# Can someone explain this code to me? mystery parameters

Tags: parameters

I am having trouble figuring out how to read this code, I would appreciate it if someone could please explain it to me.
Thank you in advance

```
public class ParameterMystery {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 9;
        int y = 2;
        int z = 5;

        mystery(z, y, x);

        mystery(y, x, z);
    }



    public static void mystery(int x, int z, int y) {
        System.out.println(z + " and " + (y - x));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 and 4

9 and 3
```

Comment: just google them out...

Answer (score 0):

Inside 'mystery' the letters used to name the variables represent different variables (different scope) than when they're used in main - the `x` in main(...) is not the same `x` inside mystery(...)

Answer (score 0):

Remember, just because the input variables have names, doesn't mean that they are assigned to the parameter with the same name in the function call. The second input parameter is always printing first, and then the subtraction of the 3rd and 1st. This is a 'trick' to force your brain to think about scope.